# wxPython - Dynamically resize image when frame is maximized

Tags: image, python-2.7, wxpython

I want two images placed side-by-side to increase in size when the frame is resize (maximized). How do I achieve that?

```
import wx

class MyFrame2 ( wx.Frame ):

    def __init__( self, parent ):
        wx.Frame.__init__ ( self, parent, id = wx.ID_ANY, title = wx.EmptyString, pos = wx.DefaultPosition, size = wx.Size( 500,300 ), style = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE|wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL )

        self.SetSizeHintsSz( wx.DefaultSize, wx.DefaultSize )

        bSizer11 = wx.BoxSizer( wx.HORIZONTAL )

        self.m_bitmap3 = wx.StaticBitmap( self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.Bitmap( u"img/im1.jpg", wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY ), wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
        bSizer11.Add( self.m_bitmap3, 1, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5 )

        self.m_bitmap4 = wx.StaticBitmap( self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.Bitmap( u"img/im2.jpg", wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY ), wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
        bSizer11.Add( self.m_bitmap4, 1, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5 )


        self.SetSizer( bSizer11 )
        self.Layout()

        self.Centre( wx.BOTH )

    def __del__( self ):
        pass

app = wx.App(0)
MyFrame2(None).Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your pastebin code

```
import wx

class MyFrame2 ( wx.Frame ):

    def __init__( self, parent ):
        wx.Frame.__init__ ( self, parent, id = wx.ID_ANY, title = wx.EmptyString, pos = wx.DefaultPosition, size = wx.Size( 500,300 ), style = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE|wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL )
        self.SetSizeHintsSz( wx.DefaultSize, wx.DefaultSize )
        bSizer11 = wx.BoxSizer( wx.HORIZONTAL )
        self.img1=wx.Image("1.bmp", wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY)
        self.img2=wx.Image("1.bmp", wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY)
        self.m_bitmap3 = wx.StaticBitmap( self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.BitmapFromImage(self.img1), wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
        bSizer11.Add( self.m_bitmap3, 1, wx.EXPAND, 0 )
        self.m_bitmap4 = wx.StaticBitmap( self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.BitmapFromImage(self.img2))
        bSizer11.Add( self.m_bitmap4, 1, wx.EXPAND, 0 )
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_SIZE, self.onResize)
        self.SetSizer( bSizer11 )
        self.Layout()
        self.Centre(wx.BOTH)

    def __del__( self ):
        pass

    def onResize(self, event):
        # self.Layout()
        frame_size = self.GetSize()
        frame_h = (frame_size[0]-10) / 2
        frame_w = (frame_size[1]-10) / 2
        img1 = self.img1.Scale(frame_h,frame_w)
        img2 = self.img2.Scale(frame_h,frame_w)
        self.m_bitmap3.SetBitmap(wx.BitmapFromImage(img1))
        self.m_bitmap4.SetBitmap(wx.BitmapFromImage(img2))
        self.Refresh()
        self.Layout()

app = wx.App(0)
MyFrame2(None).Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

Note: a single `self.Bind`
the size of the `Scale` is based on half of the frame size and the images are scaled from the original images each time, otherwise they slowly get more and more distorted.

Comment: Are the `-10`s there to account for the height of the window frame border?

Comment: @JonathanW. The -10 adjustment is made to both the height and width, to ensure the resultant images are seperated and within the frame.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to bind to `wx.EVT_SIZE` since that is the event that is fired when you resize the frame. Then in that handler, you will want to update the image's size. You can use the `Scale()` method from `wx.Image` to change the image's size. Note that you will probably want to scale the image in such a way that you maintain it's aspect ratio or it will look weird when it gets stretched.

Here's an example based loosely on my [tutorial](https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/03/26/creating-a-simple-photo-viewer-with-wxpython/) for a Photo Viewer from a few years ago:

```
import os
import wx

class PhotoCtrl(wx.App):
    def __init__(self, redirect=False, filename=None):
        wx.App.__init__(self, redirect, filename)
        self.frame = wx.Frame(None, title='Photo Control', size=(400, 400))
        self.image_loaded = False
        self.current_size = self.frame.GetSize()
        self.filepath = None

        self.panel = wx.Panel(self.frame)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_SIZE, self.onResize)

        self.PhotoMaxSize = self.current_size.GetHeight() - 10

        self.createWidgets()
        self.frame.Show()

    def createWidgets(self):
        instructions = 'Browse for an image'
        img = wx.EmptyImage(240,240)
        self.imageCtrl = wx.StaticBitmap(self.panel, wx.ID_ANY,
                                         wx.BitmapFromImage(img))

        instructLbl = wx.StaticText(self.panel, label=instructions)
        self.photoTxt = wx.TextCtrl(self.panel, size=(200,-1))
        browseBtn = wx.Button(self.panel, label='Browse')
        browseBtn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onBrowse)

        self.mainSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

        self.mainSizer.Add(wx.StaticLine(self.panel, wx.ID_ANY),
                           0, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5)
        self.mainSizer.Add(instructLbl, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        self.mainSizer.Add(self.imageCtrl, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        self.sizer.Add(self.photoTxt, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        self.sizer.Add(browseBtn, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        self.mainSizer.Add(self.sizer, 0, wx.ALL, 5)

        self.panel.SetSizer(self.mainSizer)

        self.panel.Layout()

    def onBrowse(self, event):
        """
        Browse for file
        """
        wildcard = "JPG files (*.jpg)|*.jpg"
        dialog = wx.FileDialog(None, "Choose a file",
                               wildcard=wildcard,
                               style=wx.OPEN)
        if dialog.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
            self.photoTxt.SetValue(dialog.GetPath())
            self.onView()
        dialog.Destroy()

    def scale_image(self):
        if self.filepath:
            img = wx.Image(self.filepath, wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY)
            # scale the image, preserving the aspect ratio
            W = img.GetWidth()
            H = img.GetHeight()
            if W > H:
                NewW = self.PhotoMaxSize
                NewH = self.PhotoMaxSize * H / W
            else:
                NewH = self.PhotoMaxSize
                NewW = self.PhotoMaxSize * W / H
            img = img.Scale(NewW,NewH)
            return img


    def onView(self):
        self.filepath = self.photoTxt.GetValue()
        img = self.scale_image()
        self.imageCtrl.SetBitmap(wx.BitmapFromImage(img))
        self.panel.Refresh()
        self.image_loaded = True

    def onResize(self, event):
        print 'resizing'
        if self.image_loaded:
            if self.current_size != self.frame.GetSize():
                self.current_size = self.frame.GetSize()

                self.PhotoMaxSize = self.current_size.GetHeight() - 30
                img = self.scale_image()
                self.imageCtrl.SetBitmap(wx.BitmapFromImage(img))
                self.panel.Refresh()
                self.panel.Layout()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = PhotoCtrl()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Note that this seems to scale the image just fine, but the buttons on the bottom are getting chopped off. I'm not sure why and don't really have the time at the moment to diagnose that issue, but in general this is probably the way you want to do it.

Comment: Am not sure of how to go about it. Can you kindly provide to code?

Comment: Okay. I added a quick and dirty example

Comment: Am still struggling to get it done? See what I did here: https://pastebin.com/JN6qwbQr